# Trimming UIImage white borders

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, trim

I can't find a way to crop an image with white borders included.

[image: The image to crop]

Currently it's an UIImage, and I tried some solutions like [UIImage+Trim](https://github.com/wrep/UIImage-Trim) and [CKImageAddons](https://github.com/cmkilger/CKImageAdditions) but those libraries didn't work. I think part of the problem is that **the borders is not perfectly white** because of image compression (I think).

Has anyone find a solution for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I would use UIImage+Trim and changed the way it works to count visibly white pixels (so if RGB > 255 - small_number_that_still_makes_it_white_but_suffices_to_cut_like_5_to_10) insted of counting non-transparent.

After quick look, the counting loop is here:

```
for (NSInteger row = 0; row < height; row++) {

    for (NSInteger col = 0; col < width; col++) {

        if (fullyOpaque) {

            // Found non-transparent pixel
            if (bitmapData[row*bytesPerRow + col] == UINT8_MAX) {

                rowSum[row]++;
                colSum[col]++;

            }

        } else {

            // Found non-transparent pixel
            if (bitmapData[row*bytesPerRow + col]) {

                rowSum[row]++;
                colSum[col]++;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

and cutting is done below, and removes rowSum and colSum that are equal to 0.

Also, it seems it creates inner image that is used for counting:

```
CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, (NSUInteger)width, (NSUInteger)height, 8, (NSUInteger)bytesPerRow, NULL, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
```

Using a grayscale image instead should work as easy way to change it from transparency testing to color testing.

Edit: ok, solution:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)transparencyInsetsByCuttingWhitespace:(UInt8)tolerance
{
    // Draw our image on that context
    NSInteger width  = (NSInteger)CGImageGetWidth([self CGImage]);
    NSInteger height = (NSInteger)CGImageGetHeight([self CGImage]);
    NSInteger bytesPerRow = width * (NSInteger)sizeof(uint8_t);

    // Allocate array to hold alpha channel
    uint8_t * bitmapData = calloc((size_t)(width * height), sizeof(uint8_t));

    // Create grayscale image
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, (NSUInteger)width, (NSUInteger)height, 8, (NSUInteger)bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);

    CGImageRef cgImage = self.CGImage;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, rect, cgImage);

    // Sum all non-transparent pixels in every row and every column
    uint16_t * rowSum = calloc((size_t)height, sizeof(uint16_t));
    uint16_t * colSum = calloc((size_t)width,  sizeof(uint16_t));

    // Enumerate through all pixels
    for (NSInteger row = 0; row < height; row++) {

        for (NSInteger col = 0; col < width; col++) {

            // Found darker pixel
            if (bitmapData[row*bytesPerRow + col] <= UINT8_MAX - tolerance) {

                rowSum[row]++;
                colSum[col]++;

            }
        }
    }

    // Initialize crop insets and enumerate cols/rows arrays until we find non-empty columns or row
    UIEdgeInsets crop = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

    // Top
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < height; i++) {

        if (rowSum[i] > 0) {

            crop.top = i;
            break;

        }

    }

    // Bottom
    for (NSInteger i = height - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (rowSum[i] > 0) {
            crop.bottom = MAX(0, height - i - 1);
            break;
        }

    }

    // Left
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < width; i++) {

        if (colSum[i] > 0) {
            crop.left = i;
            break;
        }

    }

    // Right
    for (NSInteger i = width - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (colSum[i] > 0) {

            crop.right = MAX(0, width - i - 1);
            break;

        }
    }

    free(bitmapData);
    free(colSum);
    free(rowSum);

    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    return crop;
}

- (UIImage *)imageByTrimmingWhitePixelsWithOpacity:(UInt8)tolerance
{
    if (self.size.height < 2 || self.size.width < 2) {

        return self;

    }

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width * self.scale, self.size.height * self.scale);
    UIEdgeInsets crop = [self transparencyInsetsByCuttingWhitespace:tolerance];

    UIImage *img = self;

    if (crop.top == 0 && crop.bottom == 0 && crop.left == 0 && crop.right == 0) {

        // No cropping needed

    } else {

        // Calculate new crop bounds
        rect.origin.x += crop.left;
        rect.origin.y += crop.top;
        rect.size.width -= crop.left + crop.right;
        rect.size.height -= crop.top + crop.bottom;

        // Crop it
        CGImageRef newImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([self CGImage], rect);

        // Convert back to UIImage
        img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];

        CGImageRelease(newImage);
    }

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Hey Rychu, thanks ! I'll try that very soon and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try as well when I get a moment

Comment: Hey ! Tried it, it works quite well. BUT sometimes it crops clouds ! For example with this photo : http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/cdfe16d45f5e11e3adc2123587d614a2_6.jpg

Comment: (I tried imageByTrimmingWhitePixelsWithOpacity:100 with this, not sure which way to go for the opacity though)

Comment: Well, clouds are quite close to white, so they can be cut off depending tolerance level. The higher tolerance value, the more will be cut. So if your image has perfectly white border, 0 will suffice, otherwise values up to 24 should be enough.

Comment: Tried it with http://bit.ly/1dSHSN3 (no white borders) and it goes completely bananas: http://cl.ly/image/2N0A0a2w2f2P

Comment: Ok, I see one thing wrong - which is weird because I fixed and I can see the fix in revision list - line if (bitmapData[row*bytesPerRow + col] == UINT8_MAX - tolerance) should have "<=" comparison. Ok, now I see, I fixed it in wrong place.