# How to get frame of specific portion on UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, frame

See the below image, I am looking for a way to get frame of "K" alphabet, I mean the blue bordered view is an `UIImageView` which loads an image of "K" alphabet. I wonder if I can get `origin` and `size` of only **"K" text** out of whole image? I can assure that, whole image background is white where text colour would always a different coloured (in this case its black). Is it possible?

[image]

Logic which (I think) should work,
- scan the `UIImage`for black color? and neglect white background color. Though we'll get max and min pixels for black color, from that we can get origin and size? Is it correct?

Comment: did you see if Core Image has anything for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trimming UIImage white borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099464/trimming-uiimage-white-borders)

Comment: @nielsbot, its not duplicate of that question! I don't want to crop anything here, I just want to get frame of black coloured text. "K" will not always fixed, it could be any alphabet too.

Comment: Your method will most definitely work, the only issue you might face is performance on large images. To solve that I suggest you to downscale the image using GPU image and get the approximate locations on the downscaled image and then move up toward original image (you may scale it more then once), this way you will not need to iterate through the whole image...

Comment: @Hemang do you have any solution for this